# How to pass numeric value from backend to a variable in angular frontend

Tags: angular, paginator

I'm very new to angular and I have this problem that looked simple in the beginning!

I'm trying to implement this angular material paginator: https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/examples

In this component I get the data from the backend,  with the method `filterMessages`.
Now, in those data there is the **total number of elements (the length for the paginator)**, which i get using `values.totalElements`. I assign this value to the `totalLength` variable. 
I want now to update the `lentgh` of the paginator with this new value.

```
    export class MessageComponent {

      constructor(...) {
      }

      totalLength: number;


      filterMessages(params: Params) {
        this.service.getMessages(params).subscribe(values => { // getMessages gets the data from the backend

          this.totalLength = values.totalElements  // here I get an value

          values = values.content;
          ...
        }, error => {
          ...
        });
      }

      // MatPaginator Inputs
      length = this.totalLength; // I want to update this with the value from the backend
      pageSize = 10;
      pageSizeOptions: number[] = [];

      // MatPaginator Output
      pageEvent: PageEvent;

}
```

Here is the .html implementation, it is the same as in the angular material example

```
<mat-paginator [length]="length"
               [pageSize]="pageSize"
               [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
               (page)="pageEvent = $event">
</mat-paginator>

<div *ngIf="pageEvent">
  <h5>Page Change Event Properties</h5>
  <div>List length: {{pageEvent.length}}</div>
  <div>Page size: {{pageEvent.pageSize}}</div>
  <div>Page index: {{pageEvent.pageIndex}}</div>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any idea, suggestion or example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the value of `totalLength` and making the wrong assumption that it is connected to the `length` attribute (just because you initialize `length = this.totalLength`). This approach can work in a worksheet but definitely doesn't work here. You're not passing a reference to `length` at initialization, just a value. So it'll work if you do something like:

```js
filterMessages(params: Params) {
  this.service.getMessages(params)
    .subscribe(
      values => {
        this.length = values.totalElements;
        ...
      }, 
      error => {...}
    );
}
```